# Given $form, how to programmatically generate its corresponding $form_state?

Tags: forms

The media_mover module contains this function, which builds a form and pre-populates default values:

```
/* step 1 */ $form = media_mover_api_configuration_base_form($configuration);
```

It also contains this function, which submits the form:

```
/* step 2 */ function media_mover_api_add_config_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
```

I would like to programmatically generate the form (step 1), and then programmatically submit the form (step 2).
Step 1 is not a problem; I am able to generate `$form`.  For step 2, I need `$form_state`.

Given `$form`, is there a way to programmatically generate its corresponding `$form_state`?  I am using Drupal 6.

This is a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.
I am able to programmatically fill out and submit a particular form by laboriously setting all the field values in `$form_state['values']`, and then calling `media_mover_api_add_config_form_submit($form, &$form_state);`

However, the process would be  much simpler if I could instead use this function, which converts a `$configuration` object into `$form`, and does all the heavy lifting:

```
$form = media_mover_api_configuration_base_form($configuration);
```

This function enters a default value into each form field. 
The only missing step, then, is to copy all these default field values from `$form` to `$form_state['values']`. I am wondering whether there is a function to do this.  Or is there a way to loop through all the fields in `$form` and extract the field-name and default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a slight improvement to this solution. The $values array didnt respect the tree format and moves [$key][$key]['value'] to $value[$key]['value'] causing sub elements with a key of "title" to overwrite the node title:

```
function mymodule_get_form_state($form){
  $values = array();
  _mymodule_form_get_values($form, &$values);
  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['values'] = $values;
  return ($form_state);
}

function _mymodule_form_get_values($element, &$values) {
  foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
    if (isset($element[$key]) && $element[$key]) {
      if (isset($element[$key]['#default_value']) && $element[$key]['#default_value']) {
        $values[$key] = $element[$key]['#default_value'];
      } else {
        // Recurse through all children elements.
        _mymodule_form_get_values($element[$key], &$values[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wager that `media_mover_api_add_config_form_submit()` is a function registered as the submit function for a form. That is, it doesn't 'submit the form,' it is called when the *user* submits the form in their web browser.

Form API lets you register functions to handle validation and submission of forms. Generally, you don't call these; you let Drupal do it.

I suppose the obvious question is: Why do you need $form_state?

Here's a link to the [Form API Quickstart Guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

UPDATE: OK given your update....

I know very little about Media Mover, though it looks useful. Poking through the code, I suggest that if you need to save a new configuration, then you just do it: `$conf = new media_mover_configuration; /* set configuration here */ $conf->save();` Or subclass the configuration if you need an encapsulated approach. You also might try asking the [project](http://drupal.org/project/media_mover)'s lead for guidance, and remind them to add more documentation to the code. :-)

Also, MM might support Features, if that helps you.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right, that the intended use of media_mover_api_add_config_form_submit() is to submit the form when the user submits the form in their web browser.  I was hoping I to use the same function to programmatically submit the form.  The reason I need $form_state is that this submit function looks at $form_state, rather than $form.

Comment: Please see my clarification above, for what I am trying to accomplish.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6) is your friend and embeds this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

form_state_defaults() will retrieve the default values. But what are you exactly trying to achieve? I'm guessing that at some point you want to set some values to be submitted? Do you have post data?

As paul-m I'm also guessing that `media_mover_api_add_config_form_submit()` is a function registered as the submit function for the form you mention. Calling this function as above won't work.

You can call the process form function though, which will build it validate and submit it if applicable.

ie: `drupal_process_form($form['#form_id'], $form, $form_state);`

Comment: Please see my clarification above, for what I am trying to accomplish.  Basically:  Is there a way to copy the default values from $form to $form_state['values']